# Distribution of the differences of the inverse of the integral of a Gaussian Distribution

Tags: statistics

I have a time series, $P$, undergoing geometric Brownian motion, which varies between $1$ and $1000$. I difference it $P(t) - P(t-1)$ and can see the differences are distributed according to a Gaussian distribution (or alternatively take log differences $\large\log \frac{P(t)}{P(t-1)}$ and see that the differences are distributed according to the log-normal distribution).

I now invert my time series to give $Q$, s.t. $Q = \frac{1}{P}$. $Q$ now varies between $0$ and $100$. I now difference $Q$ (absolute or log differences) to give the series R. What is the distribution of series R?

I look at this emperically using MATLAB;

TimeDelta = 1/(365*24*60); %1 min bars
steps = 10*252;          %10 years
loop = 10E4;              %number of simulations
mu = 10/100;               %percentage drift
Dsig = 16/100;            %annualized volatility
Szero= 100;               %Initial Price

%% The expected path
etadt=(mu-0.5*Dsig^2)*TimeDelta; %result of Ito

%% Monte Carlo Paths
P = nanmean(Szero*cumprod(exp(etadt + Dsig*sqrt(TimeDelta).*randn(loop,steps)),2));

%% Invert
Q = 1./P;

%%
subplot(211);
r = log(P(2:end)./P(1:end-1));
hist(r,100);

subplot(212);
r = log(Q(2:end)./Q(1:end-1));
hist(r,100);

The output suggests it is Gaussian.

Comment: I doubt that $P(t) - P(t-1)$ could be distributed as $\log P(t)/P(t-1)$. You maybe meant the relative move in place of the absolute one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that $P$ is a geometric Brownian motion, means that it solves the SDE 
$$d P_t = \mu P_t d t + \sigma P_t d W_t, \quad P_0 = p,$$
whose solution can be written as an explicit function of the driving Brownian motion
$$
P_t = p\ e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t }.
$$

Now it is easy to write your second time series as
$$
Q_t = \frac{1}{P_t} = \frac{1}{p}\ e^{-(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t - \sigma W_t }.
$$
From this you can see the $Q$ is also a geometric Brownian motion. So, yes, you should expect $d \log Q$ to be normally distributed.